# Opencart Register Account Error

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, user-accounts

I am currently setting up a website using `Opencart`. When registering an account on the website I obtain the following:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /homepages/2/d493065440/htdocs/sofas/system/library/mail.php on line
>   22Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /homepages/2/d493065440/htdocs/sofas/index.php:98)
>   in /homepages/2/d493065440/htdocs/sofas/system/library/response.php on
>   line 12

Does anyone know how to avoid this message? The weird thing is the account is still created? I have attached the `response.php` file. Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
<?php
class Response {
 private $headers = array();
 private $level = 0;
 private $output;

 public function addHeader($header) {
  $this->headers[] = $header;
 }

 public function redirect($url, $status = 302) {
  header('Location: ' . str_replace(array('&amp;', "\n", "\r"), array('&', '', ''), $url), true, $status);
  exit();
 }

 public function setCompression($level) {
  $this->level = $level;
 }

 public function setOutput($output) {
  $this->output = $output;
 }

 public function getOutput() {
  return $this->output;
 }

 private function compress($data, $level = 0) {
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== false)) {
   $encoding = 'gzip';
  }

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'x-gzip') !== false)) {
   $encoding = 'x-gzip';
  }

  if (!isset($encoding) || ($level < -1 || $level > 9)) {
   return $data;
  }

  if (!extension_loaded('zlib') || ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
   return $data;
  }

  if (headers_sent()) {
   return $data;
  }

  if (connection_status()) {
   return $data;
  }

  $this->addHeader('Content-Encoding: ' . $encoding);

  return gzencode($data, (int)$level);
 }

 public function output() {
  if ($this->output) {
   if ($this->level) {
    $output = $this->compress($this->output, $this->level);
   } else {
    $output = $this->output;
   }

   if (!headers_sent()) {
    foreach ($this->headers as $header) {
     header($header, true);
    }
   }

   echo $output;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The main problem here arises from `mail.php`, something is going wrong the constructor of class `Mail`, exactly in line 22 `foreach ($config as $key => $value)`, can you dump the configuration variable (right before the loop) using `error_log(var_export($config, true))` and paste the output here?

Comment: which version you're using of OC ?